# Execute PXAction after another action

Tags: acumatica

I add the autorun action "Maj BFT", but I Would like execute this action after the create IN document.

WHEN I use this code, the 2 actions are impacted.
I would like Wait 1000 only for genbft

```
public PXAction<POReceipt> Genbft;
[PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Maj BFT",Enabled = true)] 

protected virtual void genbft()
{
  Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the CreateIN document and wait for the operation to complete.  Upon completion, run the code which executes your second action.  Below is an example of waiting for a process to complete in a different screen...then it runs a second batch of operations/

```
 public delegate IEnumerable ExportDelegate(PXAdapter adapter);
    [PXOverride]
    public IEnumerable Export(PXAdapter adapter, ExportDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        baseMethod(adapter);
        TimeSpan timespan;
        Exception ex;
        while (PXLongOperation.GetStatus(Base.UID, out timespan, out ex) == PXLongRunStatus.InProcess)
        { }
        //do some more stuff after the Export action finishes
```